# Security check using an SQL call

Tags: sql, vb.net, authorization

In our latest Veracode scan for an application, I have come across the issue of Improper Resource Shutdown or Release.  It is pointing at a function.  Here's  what the code looks like:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class DAL
    Public Shared ConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection").ConnectionString


Public Shared Function CheckSecurity(ByVal strUserID As String, ByVal strOperation As String, ByVal strAppID As String) As Boolean
    Dim sbSQL As New StringBuilder
    Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
    Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand

    MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString

    sbSQL.Clear()

    sbSQL.AppendLine("EXEC dbo.CheckSecurity @UserID, @AppID, @Operation")

    sqlCmd.CommandText = sbSQL.ToString
    sqlCmd.Connection = MyConnection

    With sqlCmd.Parameters
        .Clear()
        .Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = strUserID
        .Add("@AppID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strAppID
        .Add("@Operation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strOperation
    End With


    Try
        If getDataTableFromSqlCmd(sqlCmd).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            CheckSecurity = True
        Else
            CheckSecurity = False
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New ApplicationException("SECURITY ACCESS ERROR")
    Finally
        If MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            MyConnection.Close()
        End If

        MyConnection.Dispose()
        sqlCmd.Dispose()

    End Try
End Function
```

Code for getDataTableFromSqlCMD:

```vb
Public Shared Function getDataTableFromSqlCmd(ByVal sqlCmd As SqlCommand) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim MyAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)

    Try
        sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = m_iSQLTimeOut
        MyAdapter.Fill(dt)
        getDataTableFromSqlCmd = dt

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New ApplicationException("GET DATA TABLE ERROR")
    Finally
        sqlCmd.Dispose()
        MyAdapter.Dispose()
        dt.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

As far as I can tell the resources in this code are being properly deallocated.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs more [`Using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statements. For example:

```
Public Shared Function CheckSecurity(strUserID$, strOperation$, strAppID$) As Boolean
    Try
        Using da As New SqlDataAdapter("dbo.CheckSecurity", ConnString) 
            Dim sc = da.SelectCommand, p = sc.Parameters, dt = New DataTable
            sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sc.CommandTimeout = m_iSQLTimeOut

            p.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = strUserID
            p.Add("@AppID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strAppID
            p.Add("@Operation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strOperation

            Return da.Fill(dt) > 0     ' .Fill returns the number of rows successfully added
        End Using           ' da is disposed here even if Exception occurs
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New ApplicationException("SECURITY ACCESS ERROR")
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

or

```
Public Shared Function CheckSecurity(strUserID$, strOperation$, strAppID$) As Boolean
    Try
        Using con = New SqlConnection(ConnString), 
              cmd = New SqlCommand("dbo.CheckSecurity", con)

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandTimeout = m_iSQLTimeOut

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = strUserID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AppID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strAppID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Operation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strOperation

            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Return reader.HasRows
            End Using
        End Using       ' con and cmd are closed and disposed here even if Exception occurs
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New ApplicationException("SECURITY ACCESS ERROR")
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

Some other examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023575/how-to-pass-parameters-to-sqldataadapter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566980/c-sharp-data-adapter-parameters

Comment: I used the first example and it has fixed my issue